# Guava's Rate Limiter - change rate at which permits are issued

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, guava

i want to implement a throttle mechanism in spring boot for all our application requests
i've chosen to catch all http requests in the OncePerRequestFilter and use the guava rate-limiter with 3 cases
one general with 1000 requests /second and the other two will limit requests by ip /hour/second

lets say i have 5 permits/second for an api call
and if i got 5 threads arriving at the same time or in an interval smaller than 200 milliseconds i still want them all to pass

EX.

```
0............ 1 sec
 12345 -------

0 ............ 1 sec
   ------12345
```

how can i get this to work

testing this and only gives access only to two or three threads then  blocks the rest, which is normal as the permits rate are at fixed intervals (only after 200ms)

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to provide a code sample so we can see what is producing the behavior you're trying to change.

Per the [Javadoc](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html), an idle `RateLimiter` will allow a burst of up to `permitsPerSecond` approvals, then begin issuing permits at intervals of 1/pps seconds.

It's useful to think of the `RateLimiter` as maintaining a bag of tokens. Acquiring a permit removes a token. Periodically a new token is added if there are less than pps tokens already. That isn't precisely how it actually works, but it's close enough to help you understand what's going on.

So, in other words, it seems that `RateLimiter` already behaves how you want it to. Perhaps I have misunderstood your question?